# Processor directive in MPASM

Tags: pic, assembly

I'm slightly confused about the processor directive in MPASM. Is it essentially the same thing as list? And what is the required value?

If I take an example from the template file, f88temp.asm:

```
list p=16f88
```

then this should do exactly the same thing:

```
processor 16f88
```

This seems correct but it seems I can do:

```
processor pic16f88
```

and that produces no errors. Is this just flexibility from mpasmx or is there a right and a wrong way.

If I put "16f84" in there with the processor set in MPLABX to PIC16F88, that produces a warning: "Processor superseded by command line.  Verify processor symbol." Which is fine but I'd rather that be an error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this myself, "processor" and "list p=" are equivalent.